# XCode 6 Seed iOS 8 Simulator Glitch with UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator, xcode6

Just downloaded the seed version of XCode 6 (had been running on beta 4) for awhile. I have a UIView that animates down when a View Controllers ViewDidAppear lifecycle event is called. There are a set of UITextFields in the view (it's a signup modal dialog).

The issue is that when I tap on any UITextField within the ViewController, the modal view's frame resets to where it was before it animated down. This seems to be a new glitch with XCode 6's Seed Simulator only as it works on my iPhone 5S device build and worked on beta 4's Simulator as well.

Has anyone seen any similar glitches, or is there something I'm missing?

It's being loaded by an AnimatedTransitioning

And here is a snippet of the animation code

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if animated{
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.65, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.60, initialSpringVelocity: 1.10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {() in
                self.dialog!.frame = CGRectMake(10 , 30, self.dialog!.frame.size.width, self.dialog!.frame.size.height)
                }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it works on the device and not on the simulator it's a bug. Report it to Apple at: https://bugreport.apple.com